# jq: How can I get array values based on superordinate key name

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to use [jq](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jq/info) to parse the output of https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/guidelines/5.6.json, a pretty simple JSON structure.

How can I get the "openssl" values if "configurations" is "modern" or "intermediate"?

The basic JSON structure would be:

```
{
    "configurations": { 
        "intermediate": {
            "ciphers": {
                "openssl": [
                    "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256",
                    "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256",
                    "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384",
                    "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384",
                    "ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305",
                    "ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305",
                    "DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256",
                    "DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I had to shorten it in order to avoid the "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more detail" error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all both the `modern` and `intermediate` `openssl` arrays, we can use:

```
jq '.configurations | with_entries(select([.key] | inside([ "modern", "intermediate" ])))[] | .ciphers.openssl' input
```

This will show:

```json
[]
[
  "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256",
  "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256",
  "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384",
  "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384",
  "ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305",
  "ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305",
  "DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256",
  "DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384"
]
```

---

To get a result with an object so we can see on what `key` those `openssl` certs are found, use something like:

```
jq '.configurations | to_entries | map(select([.key] | inside([ "modern", "intermediate" ])) | { "\(.key)": .value.ciphers.openssl }) | add' input
```

This will produce:

```json
{
  "modern": [],
  "intermediate": [
    "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256",
    "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256",
    "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384",
    "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384",
    "ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305",
    "ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305",
    "DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256",
    "DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384"
  ]
}
```

Comment: This would output values for .configurations.old aswell.

I'd like to get values for .configurations.modern and .configurations.intermediate only.

Comment: You only want 'modern` and `intermediate`?